# Class 'App/Person' not found in index.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a Laravel 5.6.27 application in PHP 7.2.5 where assignments can be created and given a task (task_id) and a person (person_id) to assign them to (along with dueDate, etc.). I'm getting this error when I try to load the page:

```
Class 'App/Person' not found (View: /Users/mmickelson/Sites/sacrament/resources/views/assignments/index.blade.php)
```

Here's the index.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Assignments')

@section('content')
<table>
    @foreach($assignments as $assignment)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$assignment->person->firstName}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
</table>

@endsection
```

I'm showing only the firstName of the person to help make it as simple as possible and isolate the issue.

Here's the (beginning of) the AssignmentController.php:

```
use App\Assignment;
use App\Task;
use App\Person;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AssignmentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index() {
        $assignments = Assignment::all();
        return view('assignments.index', ['assignments'=>$assignments]);
    }
...
```

Here's the (beginning of) the Assignment.php model:

```
namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Collective\Html\Eloquent\FormAccessible;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Assignment extends Model
{
    use FormAccessible;

    protected $fillable = ['person_id', 'task_id', 'dueDate', 'status', 'completedDate'];

    public function person()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App/Person');
    }
...
```

The database table for "assignments" has a person_id column, as a foreign key to the "people" table.

If I remove `person->name` from index.blade.php, leaving the  line as `<td>{{$assignment}}</td>`, the page loads fine but of course, shows the object. So, it seems to have something to do with accessing the Person associated with the Assignment.

Any ideas about what is causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a minor mistake in your model:

```
    public function person()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App/Person');
    }
```

Change the above code to below code:

```
    public function person()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Person');
    }
```

it is better if you use the below code:

```
    public function person()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Person::class);
    }
```

Person::class is same as App\Person.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! That was it. I have another Laravel app that uses the same syntax that isn't working in this so it must be a Laravel version compatibility thing. Additionally, I found that I needed to use belongsTo instead of hasOne. Those always confuse me.

Comment: Pleasure.Which laravel version you are using for that app?

Comment: belongsTo is used when we are defining the opposite of that relation.for example
User has one profile .
Profile belong to user

Answer (score 3):

I guess this issue because the name of class is wrong `App/Person` should be `App\Person`
and you can write it like the following:

```
public function person()
{
    return $this->hasOne(\App\Person::class);
}
```

Comment: Normally `Person::class` would be sufficient since most models share the same namespace (`App`)

Comment: yes you are right @Devon because both classes have the same namespace